# Convert "Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008" to suitable format for import in MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, sqldatatypes

I have data in Excel .csv File in which one columns contains date in format "Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008".
I have to import this data in MySQL.
Is there any suitable data type that supports this format Or I have to make changes in .csv file to import this data?
I have tried TimeStamp but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think it would be easiest to just select the column in the excel spreadsheet and format the column to be a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD. The form you have does not match an existing date data type available in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Alas timezones are not handled.  But the rest is done thus:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008",
                   "%a %b %d %H:%i:%s EDT %Y");
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE("Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008", "%a %b %d %H:%i:%s EDT %Y") |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2008-05-21 00:00:00                                                     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Either `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` would handle a full date and time like you have.  (Or you could ignore the 00:00:00 and put it into a `DATE`.)

Are you using `LOAD DATA`?  There is a trick to it to do the conversion inside the LOAD; see the ref manual.  Here are some hints:

1. capture the string into @x
2. SET the column to `STR_TO_DATE(@x, "...")`

Ref manual:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format  and str-to-date later on that page.